# No sound from internal speakers but headphones work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hp, headphones

I installed ubuntu in my hp envy(Y013cl) laptop.Everything works fine but no sound coming from my laptop's internal speaker but working from headphones.

These are my laptops sound configuration.Please help.

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Conexant CX8200

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 <==
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI

cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.4.0-29-generic.